# Were any brain fusion experiments ever conducted?

Tags: brain

Did anybody ever conduct experiments on fusing living brains?

Comment: You mean this? http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2013/02/28/inter-continental-mind-meld-rats_n_2781469.html

Comment: @dd3 no. this seems not to be fusion, but rather a crude transmission of some signals. I am interested in attempts to grow the brains together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The odds of that are really very slim. "Growing brains" in vitro is rather difficult, and it appears that no one has created the brain of a real organism, but [they have created "brains" from cultured dissociated neurons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_brain#Growing_an_isolated_brain).

Fusing brains is complicated by the fact that you need to make the appropriate synaptic connections between neurons, and what exactly are the appropriate connections is still being worked out.  As a side note, this is one of the goals of the [BRAIN Initiative](http://www.whitehouse.gov/infographics/brain-initiative).

The closest I believe people have come to anything approaching fusion are brain transplants in non-human animals.  This might be the closest thing to an in vivo fusion, especially if it is only a partial brain transplant.  This is discussed a bit [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_transplant#Partial_brain_transplant).

Comment: I did not find anything about brain fusion following your link to the brain initiative...

Comment: No, the point is they are working out the behavioral circuits in the brain. Any sort of fusion is dependent on making the right connections. We don't know what most of them are, so that makes it hard to make successful fusions.